# How to modify the height of a lightning-combobox dropdown?

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-combobox

I have a lwc combobox and I wanted to control the number of options shown.
I tried a lot of CSS and slds existed on the internet but I couldn´t changed it.
Could anyone help me?

```
<div class="slds-modal__content"  style="overflow:visible;" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Código do Critério" value={criteriaNumber} readonly></lightning-input>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <label class='slds-form-element__label'>Ativo</label>
                        <lightning-input type="checkbox" name="isActive" checked={isActive} onchange={handleIsActive}></lightning-input>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>

            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                    <lightning-combobox 
                        name="specialtyType"
                        label="Segmento"
                        value={typeSpecialtyValue}
                        options={typeSpecialty}
                        disabled={isDisabled}
                        dropdown-alignment="auto"
                        onchange={handleTypeSpecialty} 
                        required>
                    </lightning-combobox>
                    </template>

                    <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-input type="text" label="Segmento" value={typeSpecialtyValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                    <lightning-combobox
                        name="specialtyGroup"
                        label="Grupo de Especialidade"
                        value={specialtyGroupValue}
                        options={specialtyGroup}
                        disabled={isDisabled}
                        dropdown-alignment="auto"
                        onchange={handleSpecialtyGroup} 
                        required>
                    </lightning-combobox>
                    </template>

                    <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-input type="text" label="Grupo de Especialidade" value={specialtyGroupValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>

            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                    <lightning-combobox 
                        name="specialty"
                        label="Especialidade"
                        value={specialtyValue}
                        options={specialty}
                        disabled={isDisabled}
                        dropdown-alignment="auto"
                        onchange={handleSpecialty} 
                        required>
                    </lightning-combobox>
                    </template>
                        
                    <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-input type="text" label="Especialidade" value={specialtyValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <template if:false={isDependent}>
                        <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="cost"
                            data-id="cost"
                            label="Custo"
                            value={costValue}
                            options={cost}
                            disabled={isDisabled}
                            dropdown-alignment="auto"
                            onchange={handleCost} 
                            required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                        </template>

                        <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                            <lightning-input type="text" label="Custo" value={costValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                    <template if:true={isDependent}>
                        <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="detail"
                            label="Motivo"
                            value={detailValue}
                            options={detail}
                            disabled={isDisabled}
                            dropdown-alignment="auto"
                            onchange={handleDetail} 
                            required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                        </template>

                        <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                            <lightning-input type="text" label="Motivo" value={detailValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>

            <template if:true={isDependent}>
                <lightning-layout >
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                        <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="modal"
                            label="Modal"
                            value={modalValue}
                            options={modal}
                            disabled={isDisabled}
                            dropdown-alignment="auto"
                            onchange={handleModal} 
                            required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                        </template>

                        <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                            <lightning-input type="text" label="Modal" value={modalValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                        </template>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                        <template if:false={isDisabled}>
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="company"
                            label="Empresa"
                            value={companyValue}
                            options={company}
                            disabled={isDisabled}
                            dropdown-alignment="auto"
                            onchange={handleCompany} 
                            required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                        </template>

                        <template if:true={isDisabled}>
                            <lightning-input type="text" label="Empresa" value={companyValue} disabled></lightning-input>
                        </template>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>

                <lightning-layout>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                        <lightning-input type="number" name="value" label="Valor" disabled={isDisabled} 
                        value={value} data-id="value" max-length="6" step="0.01" onchange={handleValue} required></lightning-input>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </template>
        </div>
```

Below there are some images:

[image: the ideia is that the option wouldn´t go beyond the modal boundary]

Comment: Bom dia, Bruno. Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not add code only as an image - either instead of the image, or in addition to the image, add your code as text - preferrably set apart with three backticks (```) above and below the code in order to format it as code. This is for multiple reasons: 1) It is not good for accessibility for SFSE users with screen readers (the screen readers will likely not read the text in an image), and 2) it makes it harder for someone to help you with your code since they cannot copy it and paste it in their own editor or org.

Comment: could you add CSS or JS related to this field? What are you trying to do with said combobox, make the length smaller or change the options shown based on certain criteria?

Comment: hi! I didn´t make an css file and everyone I tried looking in the internet didn´t work.

Comment: What I´m trying to do is making the length smaller, so It won´t surpass the modal.

Answer (score 0):

you can try =  slds-dropdown_length-10